# Drag drop files on VMware from Guest OS to Guest OS

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I have VMware on my Mac Mini. And I have two Guest OS' running, one is Ubuntu 12.04 and the other is Windows 8 Pro (Bizspark Edition).

I know I can drag drop files from Guest OS to the Host OS' desktop.

My question is, is there a workaround or a hack script to drag drop files from the Guest OS to the other Guest OS? Can we use any third party apps to achieve this?

Comment: Was looking for a fix to this from sometime now, and this is fix is very low on VMware's priority list at the moment. VirtualBox is far far away from this!

Answer (score 0):

While not particularly sophisticated, one thing you could do is set up a link to a shared folder with the Host OS on the desktops of both virtual OSes.  (That is, a symlink to a folder on a shared drive with both of the Virtual OSes from the Host OS.)

Do keep in mind that the files won't be on the actual .vdi though - they'll still be on the hard drive of the host.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a shared folder on the host computer could work, but you could also try using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) on the two guest VMs. Until this is supported in VMWare tools you will have to use one of these methods.